# tkinter GUI does not terminate with 'X' when using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am running a simple tkinter application that plots some data with an animated graph. When using `matplotlib.figure.Figure` and `add_subplot`, when I close the window with the upper-menu 'X' button (windows default) the program terminates well. Working code:

```
self.f = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
self.ax = self.f.add_subplot(111)
```

Now, when I try to use `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` together with `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid`, then the 'X' does close the window but the program keeps running.

```
self.f = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
self.ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=4)
```

I've tried adding `matplotlib.pyplot.close("all")` at the end of the program but the app doesn't exit the `mainloop` at all:

```
app = myApp()
app.mainloop() # doesn't exit
plt.close("all") # doesn't get executed
```

Any possible reason and alternatives?

PS: Using `self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)` doesn't work (where self is the `tk.TK` instance).

Comment: Using `pyplot` in a GUI application like tkinter can lead to problems due to the GUI mainloop and the pyplot state machine both trying to manage the same objects. I would recommend not using pyplot at all when embedding matplotlib in GUIs; this allows to circumvent such problems from the start.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest things like that won't be gracefully handled even with the use of threads / processes? Also, are you aware if such issues occur with other Python GUI frameworks such as wxPython and PyQt/Pyside?

Comment: Such things can occur when combining pyplot with any other framework which starts an eventloop. You can treat pyplot isolated, i.e. if the GUI does not show any plot itself, but as said, the easiest is really to get rid of pyplot in your code completely. There should never be any reason to use pyplot at all (it's just a convenience thing if you don't want to create your own GUI - which you do here anyways)

Answer (score 2):

You can try handling the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` event and close all plots like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_closing():
   plt.close("all")
   app.destroy()

app = myApp()
.
.
.
app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The "all" in plt.close() is what, after trying many similar yet different approaches, finally did the trick for me. Thanks!